# Xpath error: no such element: unable to locate. Using sublime text editor with latest release chrome80 and its webdrivers

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have tried to find an element by XPath multiple ways but couldn't do it.

Code:

```
select_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//href[@text()='3:00 PM' and @data-day_ident='2021-05-25']")
```

HTML:

```
<a href="/" class="res-timeslot-select" data-day_ident="2021-05-25" data-start_int="1621980000000" data-timeslot_id="608ef96a8c15190007f9b015">3:00 PM</a>
```

I took out the tag styling because it was referring to the link.

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//href[@text()='3:00 PM' and @data-day_ident='2021-05-25']"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question by adding an explanation. Please also edit/format your question to make it easy to see codes, text, etc.

Comment: Hello, I tried my best to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath is looking for an element with tag `href`, which does not exist. The element in question has tag `a`. Without seeing the rest of your HTML I can't be 100% sure, but based on what you've posted maybe this xpath will work:

```
"//a[@text()='3:00 PM' and @data-day_ident='2021-05-25']"
```

Edit: if you are trying to just scrape the time/date from the options/links that appear on the page, the following should work:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.res-timeslot-select')
for element in elements:
    print(element.text + ' on ' + element.get_attribute('data-day_indent'))
```

Comment: No its still the same error. This is the html [link](https://reserve.anytimefitness.com/clubs/2946). If you inspect on any time like 3:00PM to reserve that time. You can view their html code. I am trying to grab that 3:00 PM or any give time link.

Comment: That element does not exist in the link you provided. If you are trying to grab the text you shouldn't use it to identify the element.

Comment: That said, I added an edit to my answer with a way to grab the text from each of those link elements.

Answer (score 0):

To select a time slot with XPath according to the date and time you can use following XPath to select the only available time slot for May 23:

```
driver.find_elementss_by_xpath('//a[@data-day_ident='2021-05-23']')
```

To select `0:00` time slot on May 24 you can use this:

```
//a[@data-day_ident='2021-05-24' and (text()='0:00')]
```

To select `1:30` time slot on May 24 use this

```
//a[@data-day_ident='2021-05-24' and (text()='1:30')]
```

And so on.
I hope it's clear now how to pick any other time slot there according to the date and time.

Comment: thanks, but if we are choosing by css selector (.res-timeslot-select) is common among all the dates. So that's why i want to grab specific time using Xpath. Please help me create a relative Xpath for a specific time slot on given date. I choose 25-05-2021 because i wrote few lines of code before which logs me into their system and that's why i was having access of more time slots.

Comment: No problem, but I see there only 3 available slots: 1 for 23 May and 2 for 24 May. To see more there is a need to login while I have no credentials.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope now it's clear?

Answer (score -1):

There are two issues with the locator you posted.

```
//href[@text()='3:00 PM' and @data-day_ident='2021-05-25']
  ^ href is an attribute of an A tag, not an element
       ^ remove @
```

1. There is no element `href`. The element is the A tag.
2. `@text()` should be `text()`. The `@` symbol is for attributes but `text()` is a method.

So, your XPath should be

```
//a[text()='3:00 PM' and @data-day_ident='2021-05-25']
  ^ A is the element
```

The problem with THIS one is that slot is not currently available. The only slots that are available right now are 5/23 1:30PM, 5/24 12:00AM, and 5/24 1:30AM. Your locator is looking for 5/25 3:00PM. If you changed it to

```
//a[text()='1:30 PM' and @data-day_ident='2021-05-23']
```

it would work.

Comment: There are much more than 3 available slots we can see without logging in. To see more there is a need to register and log in. The topic starter is logged in, so he can see much more than these 3 slots.

Comment: @Prophet I'm still seeing 3 slots without logging in but that's really irrelevant to the question. The point is the two mistakes that were made that need to be corrected for the locator to work.